# Bash - Grepping nc output in a for loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, netcat

I'm currently trying to grep the output for a nc in a bash single line loop, to only show me lines with `open`string within. I've already tried `--line-buffered` with no success. Can anybody give me a light about what I'm doing wrong? Here goes the command:

`root@kali:~# for host in $(seq 200 254); do nc -nvv -w 1 -z 192.168.15.$host 80 | grep --line-buffered "open"; done`

Comment: What do you expect this to do? On port 80, you normally have HTTP servers. HTTP servers will expect incoming connections to send an HTTP request. `nc` is not for HTTP request (unless you want to make them by hand, which is ill-advised).

Comment: You're absolutely right about `80` ports and `HTTP` servers. There's no big deal in make this requests manually, the output will look a little nasty for reading, but, that's not the point. I'm trying to perform a port scan for open `80/HTTP` ports (that's the reason for -z and -w 1 as parameters) I know that `nmap` could do it for me like a charm, but grepping this kind of buffer is being a pain for me for a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect `stderr` to `stdout` so you can `grep` it.
You can do that by putting `2>&1` anywhere between `do` and `|`.

Comment: It is purposeful to not provide any input. I just want to probe if a port is open or not. `nc` is designed for that, allowing me scan for listening daemons, without sending any data to them. And, it works great, but is being impossible to me grep for lines where `open` string is shown. I guess that's because bash executes all `nc` stream and only after completing it, try to grep its output. Any clue? :(

Comment: Oh, I see. The didn't notice nor was familiar with the -z option ... The info you're getting from nc due to the -vv flags must go to stderr. Redirect it to stdout ( `nc 2>&1 .. ` ) so you can `grep` it.

Comment: When I do `nc -nvv -w 1 -z 127.0.0.1 80 ` with nginx on, I get `Connection to 127.0.0.1 80 port [tcp/*] succeeded!`, though.  But you may have the other `nc`.

Comment: That's it! Redirecting `stderr` to `stdout` worked great! Thanks, PSkocik!

Comment: And, regarding your output to `nc` command, it's okay. It's showing to you that you got port `80` open in your machine. If you stop `nginx` and run `nc` again, you'll get a connect timeout message. You can try to issue this command aiming other hosts that you own. It's useful to enumerate which hosts got open ports. If you want to go further in port scanning, I recommend `nmap`. Cheers!